# I need to be able to load multiple pages at the same time or customize the page stack in some other way

Tags: flutter

I have a 3-step registration process.  If the application is stopped during any of these phases, it will resume from the last screen shown on the next restart.  By doing so, however, I am no longer able to call the Navigator.pop because the pages before the one opened are never loaded.  Is it possible to load multiple pages at once?  Or create an always default page stack?

Comment: Take a look at [preload_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not what I was looking for. Or maybe I haven't figured out how to use it. I have not found any online resources

Comment: Consider the registration process consisting of the following pages: first page, email registration, data registration, and telephone number registration. If, at a certain point in the registration (for example I have only completed the email registration), and the program is closed, when the application is restarted the data registration page will be shown directly. In this way, if from the data registration page I want to return to the email registration page, I cannot, because it has never been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the registration process is a three step process, use `PageView` with three screens passed to it, when moving to next, use the `PageController.jumpTo(pageNumber)`.

Now, to resume the registration process to the last page left,

1. Set up a function to store current position of the `PageView` in the `SharedPreferences`.
2. On `initState` when app is opened, read this saved value, if the value exists, initialize the `PageController` with `initialPage` parameter set to the last page left, if the value doesn't exist, keep it to default `initialPage` value (0). This way it will always show the last page selected, resuming the registration process.

You can also load the last entered values in the screens passed to the `PageView`.

This way, without using any third party package, you can create proper mechanism which fulfills your requirement.

Comment: A thousand thanks! This doesn't solve my problem, but it gets around it...smart.

Comment: @THEMANUX Your welcome for that but do remember to disable the Swipe gestures to change screens functionality, to do that, set the scrolling physics as  `PageView(physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics())`.

Comment: A thousand thanks. Now I just have a few problems with the heroes and animations between screens